# Setup flutter and android studio in mac 2020

Tags: flutter, java-8, flutter-dependencies

I have installed flutter and android studio giraffe on my macbook
Here is what the zshrc file looks like

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Users/davete0302/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_391.jdk/Contents/Home"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME:/Users/davete0302/Desktop/flutter/bin":$PATH
```

I am getting this error when running the app in android studio

> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
> Required by:
> project :connectivity_plus
> > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.2' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.2')

I have downloaded jdk 21 and jdk 1.8 which one do i use?

Comment: Did you check if the directory at path `/Users/davete0302/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_391.jdk/Contents/Home` really exists? What happens if you type in `cd /Users/davete0302/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_391.jdk/Contents/Home` on the command line

Comment: @jraufeisen i updated the error. The java home is now detected but unable to run the app. I feel like the issue lies on the jdk I use